# How to politely request the bus driver to stop the bus if they overstep my stop?

Tags: transports

I am in [Île-de-France](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%8Ele-de-France) and used to take the bus to commute to my work.
It so happened today that the bus driver (whom I see almost every other day), forgot to stop the bus where I want to get off. I pushed the STOP button and the red STOP sign was ON.

I cried “meisseur s'il vous plaît,” they didn't pay any attention. Finally “excuse-moi” did the trick.

Now I am looking for a French equivalent or specific for

> Please stop the bus, I need to get off here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just before the stop,

> Monsieur, j'aimerais descendre ici s'il vous plait.

If he misses the stop,

> Monsieur, j'aimerais descendre au prochain arrêt s'il vous plait.

If you have a chance to talk to him closely,

> J'ai essayé de vous indiquer que l'arrêt précédent était celui qui m'intéressait en appuyant sur le bouton, mais vous n'avez pas été en mesure d'arrêter l'autobus.

Comment: These suggestions, even after being corrected to be grammatically correct, aren't really what would a native French speaker would have used. You generally don't say « *J'aimerais descendre ici* » but « *je dois descendre ici* » or simply « *je descend ici* »;  « *l'arrêt qui m'intéressait* » is odd, I would have said « *l'arrêt où j'aurais dû descendre* »; « *vous n'avez pas été en mesure d'arrêter l'autobus* » is unlikely what happened (unless the brakes were failing or the bus was sliding on ice), you should have stated « *mais vous ne vous êtes pas arrêté*.»

Comment: @jlliagre  Ma réponse est polie. La tienne est directe.

Comment: Ça fait longtemps que tu n'as pas pris le bus ? 1) On ne signale pas oralement au chauffeur qu'on veut descendre au prochain arrêt : on appuie sur le bouton d'arrêt. 2) S'il oublie de s'arrêter, on n'attend pas le prochain arrêt, on lui crie : "monsieur/madame vous vous êtes pas arrêté(e) !" et il pile le bus en plein milieu de la route pour te laisser descendre. 3) Je vois pas bien à quel moment tu peux interpréter ton texte théâtral sur son oubli de s'arrêter.

Comment: @Simon Déchamps, oui tu as raison. Ça fait longtemps que je n'ai pas pris le bus. Quand j'indique au chauffeur de la Rolls-Royce d'arreter, il le fait tout de suite...  Ciao Mr "vous vous êtes pas"

Comment: A partir d'un certain niveau de politesse/formalité, ca en devient presque trop. La dernière phrase bien que syntaxiquement correcte et effectivement très polie, n'est absolument pas réaliste dans la vie de tous les jours, ni complètement exacte : "vous n'avez pas été en mesure de..." est au mieux un euphémisme, la probabilité étant grande que le chauffeur a juste oublié, ce qui arrive...

Answer (score 9):

First, did you push the button to tell him you wanted to get off at the next station? If no, you shouldn't ask him to stop between two stations.

If you did and he forgot, so something like `Excusez-moi, je descendais là` or `Excusez-moi, vous avez oublié de vous arrêter` will be nice.

Comment: Yes, I pushed the STOP button and it was loud and clear :)... I edited the question to include this information. Please edit your answer accordingly.

Comment: @I don't need to edit my answer since the second part is about the driver forgetting to stop despite you pushed the button.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps the driver didn't understood your first query if you pronounced it the way you write it *meisseur*, which sounds like *messieurs* so is directed to several men, not a single one. *Monsieur* (pronounced "muh-syuh", IPA /mə.sjø/) would have been better.

In any case, note that unless there is an real emergency situation, a driver is not allowed to let people leave a bus between regular stops so he took on his own to break the rules and find a location where he was able to do it safely.

Answer (score 3):

**By entering the bus, you can ask:**

> > Excusez-moi vous allez bien a ...? / sorry are you going to ...? 
> >     Ce bus s’arrête a ...? / This bus stop at ...?

**Before your stop, in addition of pressing the stop button etc ... you can say:**

> Monsieur je descends au prochain arrêt. / Mr. I get off at the next stop.

(notice that by using the present tense you emphasis the fact that it's 'not a question' but an actual fact (which can sometimes be taken as an order).
If you want to be softer, you can say:

> Pouvez-vous me laisser descendre au prochain arrêt? / Can you let me get off at the next stop?

**You can be even more subtle and ask:**

> Est-ce que l’arrêt ... est encore loin? / Is the stop ... still far?

which should result in having the driver telling you that it's the coming one (and also you made clear the fact that you want to get off at that one) -> A nice (even a bit longer) way to ask him to drop you there.

Answer (score 1):

"Monsieur, l'arret s'il vous plait!"

But only if you're still within reasonable reach of the stop, if you wake up 2 blocks later it's too late for the bus to stop.