# How do I say “hold the bus”?

Tags: traduction, transports

When touring Paris on Les Cars Rouge, I saw my bus begin to pull away from the bus stop. I wanted to call out to the driver to hold the bus for me as there wouldn’t be another bus for quite a while. Is there a French equivalent to “hold the bus”?

Comment: "Hold the bus" to wait someone else or just you ? What would be the difference with "please wait for me" or something like that?

Comment: @XouDo Even though it appears ambiguous, for some reason we do indeed say "hold the bus" even when it's just us. Might make an interesting question in pragmatics...

Comment: Related: https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/24900/how-to-politely-request-the-bus-driver-to-stop-the-bus-if-they-overstep-my-stop

Comment: @XouDo Please wait for me (*Attendez*) could be ambiguous and not make the point  who you are talking to. In a similar situation in France I'd say *Ne démarrez-pas tout de suite* which is also asking for the driver to interact with the bus without having to name the vehicle. *Démarrer* is clear enough in French without having to specify *le bus*.

Comment: @None En réfléchissant, je ne vois pas vraiment de cas où "ne démarrez pas" est utile. D'une part, "Démarrer" est un peu ambigu entre le fait de mettre le contact et de partir vraiment. Ensuite, si le chauffeur doit quitter son arrêt, on n'a pas à lui ordonner ça. Si on le fait, c'est en mentionnant la raison : attendre soi-même ou une autre personne, auquel cas "Attendez-moi, s'il vous plaît" ou bien "Attendez la dame s'il vous plaît" convient très bien.

Comment: @XouDo *ne démarrez-pas* is just the equivalent of "Hold the bus" which is what the OP is asking for, I can't see that they say please or wait in their question, it's just "Hold the bus". If you don't like *démarrer*, *ne partez-pas* is to my mind the next best thing.

Answer (score 12):

A spontaneous shout to the driver would be "Attendez !" or "Attendez-moi !"

If you want to ask people to keep the bus from pulling away, eg by informing the driver, you can say "Retenez le bus !"

Comment: En France je pense qu'on n'utiliserait pas *retenir* dans ce contexte mais plutôt *Ne démarrez pas tout de suite*, « Attendez s'il vous plaît, ne démarrez pas tout de suite ! ». ¶ In France I expect people would not use *retenir* here but *ne pas démarrer* : *Attendez s'il vous plaît, ne démarrez pas tout de suite !*

Comment: @None: the "retenez le bus!" is correct if aimed at people around/near the bus, in hope that they signal the chauffeur (who, being inside a closed bus, is very likely to not hear the one trying to get to the bus).

Comment: @OlivierDulac The question says: " I wanted to call out to the driver to hold the bus ".

Comment: Attendez-moi, oui. retenir, non.

Answer (score 1):

There's no equivalent or designated expression for this particular situation. What i would've say is "Attendez!" or "Attendez moi!" Just like you would say "Wait for me!" in english.

Comment: *Ne démarrez-pas tout de suite*  is an equivalent, it is not ambiguous as *attendez* could be, and, like the English "hold the bus" is pointing to the driver's interacting with their vehicle.

Answer (score 0):

You can also shout "CONDUCTEUR ! ATTENDEZ s'il vous plait !".

Comment: « Monsieur» rather than *conducteur*, it's more polite.

Comment: @None A matter of opinion, as it appears to me, "conducteur" is a function (activity or purpose of a person) and so you identify this person almost certainly in a unique manner; moreover a reference to someone's chosen profession can't be in any way, whatsoever, connoting any notion of impoliteness. Personnally I do not think there is any breach of the rules of politeness.

Comment: If not politeness, a breach of idiomaticity. If you want to make clear who you are talking to, that would be ***Chauffeur ! Attendez s'il vous plait !*** The word *conducteur* is too formal to be used in such a situation.

Comment: @jlliagre Difficile d'exiger de quiconque de s'en tenir à la confortable familiarité à laquelle on adhère soi-même :  TLFi « A.− Celui, celle qui conduit, guide, dirige un véhicule, des animaux. Conducteur de locomotives, mauvaise conductrice  ».

Comment: @LPH La question n’est pas la définition, c’est juste qu’il n’est pas idiomatique de dire « conducteur » pour s’adresser au chauffeur. Ça reste compréhensible mais c’est bizarre.

Comment: @Didier On pourrait aussi dire, pour surprendre encore plus le chauffeur: ***Machiniste !** Attendez s'il vous plaît !* ;-)

Comment: @jlliagre Chauffe Marcel !

Comment: Là, il ne risque pas d'attendre. C'est le contraire de ce qui est demandé.

Comment: Finalement, C’est pas sorcier !